# How to add line numbers to a docx document section using python-docx

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

I am using [python-docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx) to generate some documents.

I can see that there exists a [line numbering property](http://officeopenxml.com/WPsectionLineNumbering.php) which may be applied to document sections (for the *OOXML* standard at least).

I can also see that this property is not present in the [python-docx API](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section).

I am assuming it is possible to access the underlying `sectPr` field to add the `lnNumType` tag, but I have not been able to (easily) find any examples.

Am I getting my standards confused? Or is my question just a bit obscure?

Comment: Implementation of Section is at https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/section.py ; see also https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/xmlchemy.py .  I don't see an accessor off-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the Section object, you can get the sectPr element with:

```
sectPr = section._sectPr
```

If you Google on *'python-docx workaround function OxmlElement'* you'll find examples. All elements inherit from lxml _Element so lxml manipulation works. There are also some handy other methods added by BaseOxmlElement. A basic gist would be:

```
sectPr = section._sectPr
lnNumType = OxmlElement('w:lnNumType')
lnNumType.set('fooAttrib', '42')
sectPr.append(lnNumType)
```

In many cases you'll need to attend to getting any new child elements in the right order, as the sequence is almost always prescribed.

You can find some handy analysis of the `w:sectPr` element here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/sections.html

It looks from a quick glance that you'll be able to just append a `w:lnNumType` on the end as the elements that follow it are less common. But if you wanted to be more rigorous you could use this instead of `sectPr.append()`:

```
sectPr.insert_element_before(lnNumType, (
    'w:pgNumType', 'w:pgNumType', 'w:cols', 'w:formProt', 'w:vAlign',
    'w:noEndnote', 'w:titlePg', 'w:textDirection', 'w:bidi',
    'w:rtlGutter', 'w:docGrid', 'w:printerSettings', 'w:sectPrChange',
))
```

You can see the implementation for `.insert_element_before()` here:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/xmlchemy.py#L718