# On transcribing a .docx file to a new .docx document how to insert <w:numPr> and associated data on a paragraph basis?

Tags: python, python-docx

```
for src_paragraph in src_doc.paragraphs:
                src_paragraph_format = src_paragraph.paragraph_format
                # print(src_paragraph.text)

                # Handle Headers/Footers                                        Headers not implemented
                # 
                sections = trgt_doc.sections                                    # there's only 1 section
                section = sections[0]
                footer = section.footer                                         # get the footer section of the section
                paragraph = footer.paragraphs[0]                                # footer has 1 paragraph
                paragraph.text = f'{page_number} \t\t\t {printed_time_stamp}'   

                # Transcribe paragraph settings - Build the target
                #
                trgt_paragraph = trgt_doc.add_paragraph(style = src_paragraph.style ) 

                if src_paragraph._p.pPr.numPr is not None:
                    print('\n <w:pStyle> :', src_paragraph._p.pPr.pStyle)
                    print ('<w:numPr> :', src_paragraph._p.pPr.numPr)
                    print ('\t<w:ilvl> :', src_paragraph._p.pPr.numPr.ilvl)
                    print ('\t<w:numId> :', src_paragraph._p.pPr.numPr.numId)
                    print('\n', src_paragraph.text)

                trgt_paragraph_format = trgt_paragraph.paragraph_format
                trgt_paragraph.style.name = src_paragraph.style.name
                trgt_paragraph_format.left_indent = src_paragraph_format.left_indent  # inherited from style hierarchy
                trgt_paragraph_format.right_indent = src_paragraph_format.right_indent 
                # print('S_INDENT -------|', src_paragraph_format.left_indent)
                # print('T_INDENT -------|', trgt_paragraph_format.left_indent)
                trgt_paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
                trgt_paragraph_format.widow_control = True
                font = trgt_paragraph.style.font
                font.name = 'Times'
                font.size = Pt(11)
```

I'm transcribing Word files into similar documents with the same info. content but with modifications and additions. Im building the target files by iterating through the source paragraphs then creating the target paragraph/runs.

This is mostly done but except for capturing numeric bullets. I can capture  and  but don't know, at this point, how to get these values into each target paragraph.

This is my first project with .docx data and I'm researching this as I go.

Comment: Have a search around Google on the keywords "python-docx workaround function" and you'll see some examples. The basic idea is to get to the closest parent XML element you can using a python-docx object and then use `lxml` calls from there.

Comment: On Googling the keywords but have yet to get the desired inserts to work. I've located the number bullet in the source file but have been unable to insert, using lxml, into the target file.

Answer (score 0):

In attempting to just insert into the target .docx file I'm generating I tried this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400208/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-a-docx-document-section-using-python-docx)

```
# Generate new Target file from Source File
for src_paragraph in src_doc.paragraphs:
    src_paragraph_format = src_paragraph.paragraph_format
    # Get Target section(s)
    sections = trgt_doc.sections
    section = sections[0]
    sectPr = section._sectPr
    lnNumType = OxmlElement('w:lnNumType')
    lnNumType.set('fooAttrib', '42')
    sectPr.append(lnNumType)
    print('STUBB')
```

It's line numbers here, not an outline style numbering list. I just wanted to do an initial insert to see it it would work; It didn't.

```
# Add Numbered List to Target paragraphs.
# Isolate the number bulleted paragraphs 
if src_paragraph._p.pPr.numPr:
   # SOURCE XML Paragraphs containing numPr
   print('--------------------------------------------')
   print('TEXT_SRC', src_paragraph.text,'\n')
   print('SRC ParXML \n', src_paragraph._p.xml)
   print('--------------------------------------------')
```

I'm able to find the decimal numbers in the source .docx this way; the trick is just to get that over into the target i'm generating.